# Accessing all the email IDs for each contact from the iphone contactlist through code

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.presently i am working in project but i have struck in the middle of the project because of don't know how to access all the email id's for each contact from the iphone contactlist through coding.if anybody knows about this concept can you please help me....

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you email along with their display names and contact name too:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getEmailAndPhoneOfPhoneContacts
{
    
    NSLog(@"getPhoneContacts");
    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    
    NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
    if(!iPhoneAddressBook)
    {
        DLog(@"unable to open addressBook");
    }
    //ABPerson *newPerson;
    
    NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool=nil;
    
    
    CFArrayRef allPeople=ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(iPhoneAddressBook);
    NSMutableArray *peopleArray=[NSMutableArray  arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)allPeople];
    
    BOOL shouldReleasePool=NO;
    
    NSInteger i;
   
    for(i=0;i<[peopleArray count];i++)
    {
        
        if((i&255)==0)
        {
            innerPool= [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
            shouldReleasePool=YES;
        }
        
        
        ABRecordRef record=[peopleArray objectAtIndex:i];
        
        Contact *objPhoneContact=[[Contact alloc] init];
        objPhoneContact.contactType=STATIC_CONTACT;
        
        
        
        
    CFStringRef prefixName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPrefixProperty);
    CFStringRef firstName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef middleName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNamePhoneticProperty);
    CFStringRef lastName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    CFStringRef suffixName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonSuffixProperty);
    NSMutableString *contactname =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    
    
    // concating all the names
    if (prefixName) {
        [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)prefixName]];
        CFRelease(prefixName);
    }
    if (firstName) {
        [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)firstName]];
        CFRelease(firstName);
    }
    if (middleName) {
        [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)middleName]];
        CFRelease(middleName);
    }
    if (lastName) {
        [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)lastName]];
        CFRelease(lastName);
    }
    if (suffixName) {
        [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)suffixName]];
        CFRelease(suffixName);
    }
    // if emty then get the organization property
    if (contactname == nil || [contactname length]<1) {
        CFStringRef orgName=ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
        if (orgName) {
            [contactname appendString:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString*)orgName]];
            CFRelease(orgName);
        }
        
    }
    //if still empty then assign (no name) to it
    if (contactname == nil || [contactname length]<1)
        [contactname setString:@"(no name)"];
        
        objPhoneContact.mContactName = [contactname stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
                
        [contactname release];
        contactname = nil;
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multi;
        int multiCount=0;
        
        
               
        
        multi=ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonEmailProperty);
        
        NSUInteger emailIndex_home=301;
        NSUInteger emailIndex_work=321;
        NSUInteger emailIndex_other=341;  //~400
        
        multiCount=ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
        if(multiCount ==0)
        {
            //objPhoneContact.mEmailId=@"";
        }
        else 
        {
            for( int i=0; i < multiCount; i++)
            {
                ContactProperty* objEmailContactProperty=[[ContactProperty alloc] init];
                
                objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropertyString=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
                objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName=(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
                objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName=[objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"_$!<>"]];
                
                
                if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"home"]==NSOrderedSame)
                {
                    objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_home;
                    emailIndex_home++;
                }
                else if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"work"]==NSOrderedSame)
                {
                    objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_work;
                    emailIndex_work++;
                }
                /*
                 else if([objEmailContactProperty.mDisplayName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"other"]==NSOrderedSame)
                 {
                 objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",emailIndex_other];
                 emailIndex_other++;
                 }
                 */
                else 
                {
                    objEmailContactProperty.mContactPropId=emailIndex_other;
                    emailIndex_other++;
                }
                
                objEmailContactProperty.mContactDataType=@"Email";
                
                [objPhoneContact.mPropertyArray addObject:objEmailContactProperty];
                [objEmailContactProperty release];
            }
        }
        
        if(multi)
            CFRelease(multi);
        
        [tempArray addObject:objPhoneContact];
        [objPhoneContact release];
        
        if(shouldReleasePool)
        {
            [innerPool drain];
            shouldReleasePool=NO;
        }
        
    }
    self.mPhoneContactArray=tempArray;
    CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);
    CFRelease(allPeople);
    
    
    [pool drain];
    return [tempArray autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import these two files:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

-(IBAction)showPeoplePickerController
{

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
    [menuArray removeAllObjects];
    if(menuArray ==nil)
        menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *localDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

        ABRecordID recordId = ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);
        [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",recordId] forKey:@"Record_Id"];


        //get firstname
        CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName] forKey:@"first_name"];

        //get lastname
        CFStringRef lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName] forKey:@"last_name"];

        NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
        [localDic setObject:contactFirstLast forKey:@"FullName"];


        //get EmailIds
        ABMutableMultiValueRef EmailIds = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        CFTypeRef EmailId;
        NSString *EmailLabel;


        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(EmailIds); i++) {
            EmailLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(EmailIds,i)];

            if([EmailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
            {
                EmailId = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(EmailIds,i);
                [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",EmailId] forKey:@"Email_Home"];

            }
            else if([EmailLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
            {
                EmailId = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(EmailIds,i);
                [localDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",EmailId] forKey:@"Email_Work"];
                break;
            }
        }


        [menuArray addObject:localDic];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",menuArray);

}
```

In this way you get all EmailIds of each people.

and also add these two frameworks in your project:

```
AddressBook.framework
AddressBookUI.framework
```